# Swagger Documentation - How can i get only values separated by a comma in the json request body?

Tags: annotations, swagger, swagger-php

In my case, for a DELETE operation, i will have to pass a body which looks like below.

Request body should look like:

```
[
 "Vi####1",
 "Vi####2"
]
```

But when i tried to achieve this, i always get the data type along with the value as shown below.

Request body that's getting created currently:

```
{
 "Vi####1": "string",
 "Vi####2": "string"
}
```

please find below the json creation.

```
class VirtualViewColDeleteReq
{

/**
 * @OA\Property(
 *     title="View ID",
 *     description="Segment Name",
 *     property="Vi####001"
 * )
 *
 * @var string
 */

/**
 * @OA\Property(
 *     title="View ID1",
 *     description="Segment Name",
 *     property="Vi####002"
 * )
 *
 * @var string
 */

}
```

swagger.php

```
 *     @OA\RequestBody(
 *          required=true,
 *          @OA\JsonContent(ref="#/components/schemas/VirtualViewColDeleteReq")
 *      ),
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're current setup describes an object, but look like you want a simple array with strings

```php
 *     @OA\RequestBody(
 *       required=true,
 *       @OA\JsonContent(
 *         type="array", 
 *         @OA\Items(type="string"),
 *       )
 *     )
```

For additional clarity you can provide a format  `@OA\Items(type="string", format="id"),` this is ignored by the tooling but gives a hint to the reader of the documentation.

Comment: Hey Bob, It helped me. Thanks for the solution :)